# Prevent Angular from toggling ng-view size

Tags: angularjs

I have this specific issue with the way `ng-view` renders templates. Whenever a partial is rendered, the `div` with the `ng-view` attribute slides up and then again renders with the compiled template. I tried using `ngCloak` as follows:

```
<div ng-view autscroll="true">
<!--Partials rendered here-->
</div>
```

partial.html

```
<div class="some-class" ng-cloak>

</div>
```

For better illustration:

Pre render[image: Pre template render]

Post render[image: Post template Render]

Here the dark part is the footer that's static across all pages along with the red header.

How do I prevent this jumping?

Comment: Could you add more information. Is there any styles on .some-class? Is the problem that before the render there is no white space?

Comment: @floor, yep, that's pretty much it. The white space in the screenshot is just an empty template as of now so that I could illustrate my point. But the absence of white space/general layout of the page is what I'm trying to fix

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what you are trying to render but... of course there isn't going to be "white space" before the render. There are no elements there to push the footer down. Then the render happens and there is this div with a style on it (im assuming a height or something) which pushes the content down. If you want your footer to be at the bottom maybe position fix it or make your main element or whatever is in the middle have a style with some height until the render is complete?